# Removing space between Navigation bar and banner

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, header, containers

I'm using Bootstrap to make my custom website but I have a problem. I have a big space between my banner and my navigation bar. I need to remove it without breaking the anything else.
I was searching for fix on this website and on other websites too, but none of those are working. Here's the code:

HTML: http://pastebin.com/FSFA4GhG   CSS: http://pastebin.com/TiQ1nm9h

I figured out that the problem is in the `<header>` somewhere, but I cannot fix it/find that error.

Comment: Post your code in your question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the header set at 100px (the navbar default is min-height: 50px) and change the `top` property on the `banner` id as well to 50px

Sidenote: you have 2 separate IDs set on your `navbar-collapse` div causing the mobile nav to not work correctly.

See example Snippet.

```css
body,
div,
h1,
h2,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  text-align: left;
}
header {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f00;
  z-index: 50;
  position: fixed;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
}
#banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  background: #AE1;
}
#content {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 400px;
  background: #ebe;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="container">
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MENU</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">gg 1<span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">11</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">12</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">gg2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">gg 3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div id="banner">
    <h2>BANNER</h2>

  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <p>
      CONTENT
    </p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Thank you very much! You helped me a lot!

Comment: No problem and glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, just remove the height property from your `#header` and put a correctly top property on your `#banner` (same that your nav height):

```css
body, div, h1, h2, p{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
 
    body{
        text-align: left;
    }
    header{
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 50;
        position: fixed;
        display: inline-block;
    }
 
    #banner {
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 50px;
        background: #AE1;
 
    }
 
    #content {
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        top: 400px;
        background: #ebe;
        height: 1000px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Fred WEB</title>
<!--Zobrazenie pre mobily-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
 
<!--Pridanie JQuery a Boostrapu-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
 
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
 
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">
        </script>
 
</head>
<body>
       
<div id="container">
        <header>
 
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MENU</a>
    </div>
    <div id ="menu" class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">gg 1<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">11</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">12</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">gg2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">gg 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
        </header>
 
        <div id="banner">
                        <h2>BANNER</h2>
 
        </div>
        <div id="content">
                <p>
                        CONTENT
                </p>
       
        </div>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```css
nav {
    margin: 0px !important;
  }
```

And to edit banner rule

```css
#banner {
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 50px;
        background: #AE1;
 
}
```